# Cant seem to find android restful service examples

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest, restful-authentication

This topic is a bit tricky. So far I've been able to write a restful web service with Google app engine, and that's only because of the great tutorials Google offers. What about tastypie and django for example? Are there any tutorials or books I can buy on how to get responses from them with android? What do you recommend to a good start into this advanced topic? I've looked for books but I can't find anything.

Comment: Ive looked at a few things online and it looks like they are getting a cookie... have crazy for loops for headers... Im not sure how that works.. so your saying if its restful you just make a request to the api and it's that easy?

Comment: oh ok So I might have mixed that up. If they are not restful for example.. maybe a form encoded api, how would I go about that?

Comment: isnt an webservice api restful?

Comment: Google "tastypie android client" -- matches #3 and #4 have a tutorial.

Comment: ill have a look through these. I'm trying to get good with web services knowing that is what employers want. Thanks!

Comment: Since you have `Java` and `Javascript` experience, you will really like [droidQuery](http://bit.ly/droidquery) for doing `Ajax` calls to perform `RESTful` requests on `Android`.